# How to properly design a table with field as list or set

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have a user that can have a wallet. Now, when user create a wallet I want to give him a option to create a transaction on that wallet. So, on that form I would like to have next fields, so prompt user to insert:

`Amount of transaction`, `Date`, `note of transaction`, `category of transaction`

So far I have this in Spring:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "transaction_id")
private Integer id;

private double amount;

private String note;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;
```

But I have problem with field `category`. I want to prompt user to pick from dropdown menu one of category from the list. But how to create a field `categories` that will be filled with names of categories?

I tried with:

```
@Column(name = "categories")
private List categories;
```

But I'm getting:

```
Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: transaction, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(categories)]
```

Comment: Do you really want to store the categories in one database column? Isn't it more like a OneToMany relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Spring JPA lets you handle this a couple of different ways. Since you didn't specify what **type** of thing a category is, I am assuming you want it to be a String.

#### @ElementCollection

The first, easiest, and generally recommended way is to use the `@ElementCollection`. If your categories are fairly well fixed, you can even use `enum`s for this.

```
@ElementCollection
private List<String> categories=new ArrayList<>();
```

With this, JPA will generate a second table in the database called `transaction_categories` You don't have to create an Entity for this table or anything. Everything is handled under the covers.

#### JsonB

If you are using postgres 10+ (I think) you can make a column into a JSON object. You will need the following dependency in your gradle.

```
implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.15.1'
```

And you will need to change your model thus:

```
@TypeDefs({
  @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)
})
@Entity
public class Transaction {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "transaction_id")
  private Integer id;

  private double amount;
  private String note;

  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
  @Column(name = "date")
  private Date date;

  @Type(type = "json")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  private List<String> categories=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

So long as this list does not become gigantic, it is a pretty decent solution.